# how to copy diff of two directories to a new directory?

Tags: linux, diff, directory

Suppose I have two directories : D1 and D2.

D1 ( f1, f2, f3, f4 )
D2 ( f1, f2 )

I want to copy the files in D1 , which are not in D2, to another directory D3 :

D3 ( f3, f4 )

How do I do this in linux ?

Thanx,
trinity

Answer (score 2):

Look at the 'dirdiff'-package. It allows for what you want to do.

Alternatively, this bash command-line should do it:

```
for i in `ls D1` ; do if [ -f D2/$i ]; then echo "skip $i" ; else cp D1/$i D3 ; fi  done
```

Note the back-ticks around `ls D1` - not single quotes! (On the US-keyboard it is beneath the ~(tilde))

Answer (score 0):

while copying from D1 to D3 use  -exclude specifying D2 
and it would be done...

Answer (score 0):

Just spent a good portion of a day sorting out something similar and picked up from an answer of an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891125/556643). I ended up with a fairly elaborate bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup folders for our different stages
DIST=/var/www/localhost/htdocs/dist/
DIST_OLD=/var/www/localhost/htdocs/dist_old/
DIST_UPGRADE=/var/www/localhost/htdocs/dist_upgrade/

cd $DIST

find . -type f | while read filename
do

    newfile=false
    modified=false
    if [ ! -e  "$DIST_OLD$filename" ]; then
        newfile=true
        echo "ADD $filename"
    elif ! cmp $filename $DIST_OLD$filename &>/dev/null; then
        modified=true
        echo "MOD $filename"
    fi

    if $newfile || $modified; then

        #massage the filepath to not include leading ./
        filepath=$DIST_UPGRADE$(echo $filename | cut -c3-)

        #create folder for it if it doesnt exist
        destfolder=$(echo $filepath | sed -e 's/\/[^\/]*$/\//')
        mkdir -p $destfolder

        #copy new/modified file to the upgrade folder
        cp $filename $filepath
    fi
done
```